# Rolling non-regular tetrahedron. How many orientations?

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, polyhedra

I've recently studied [rolling polyhedra graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RollingPolyhedronGraph.html). A polyhedron is rolled over its edges until it has reached all possible orientations. Ideally one more roll puts it back where it started.  For example, the [snub disphenoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SnubDisphenoid.html) has 72 orientations. If it is rolled through them all and ends back where it started with one more roll then there are 12 possible paths.

[image: rolling disphenoid paths]

I decided to look off-the-grid.  Here's the 120 states of the rolling dodecahedron in a closed path.
[image: rolling dodecahedron]

A bit too hard to simplify.  But even the tetrahedron seems challenging. Do all the triangles need angles that are rational fractions of $\pi$, or does just the sum of angles around each vertex need to be a rational fraction of $\pi$? If the sum of angles around a vertex is not a rational fraction of $\pi$ then there are infinite orientations just rolling around that vertex.

A rolling non-regular tetrahedron has $n$ orientations.  What values can $n$ be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t^2=1.92756\ldots$ be the [tetranacci constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TetranacciConstant.html).  Build this tetrahedron with edges having length $t^0, t^1, t^2, t^3$.

[image: tetranacci tetrahedron]

Under rolling this tetrahedron has only 12 orientations.

[image: Tetranacci tetrahedron rolled]

A different tetrahedron with 12 orientations:

[image: tetra12]

A tetrahedron with 20 orientations

[image: tetra20]

A tetrahedron with 8 orientations when rolled:

[image: tetra 8]